# How to set auto resize when window size increase in javafx?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

When i resize window the hbox size is fix and that's why is not increasing when i increase the size of window. How to auto resize or set to the window size whenever user increase the size of window? 
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXHamburger?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <HBox layoutX="-6.0" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="807.0" style="-fx-background-color: #42A5F5;">
         <children>
            <JFXHamburger prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Please give me suggestion how to build a better UI in javafx give me sources if you know.

Comment: The `HBox` presumably has a fixed size because of some of the code you have written. Unless you post that code, no-one can really help.

Comment: don't give -1  give me links if the answer already in stackoverflow!

Comment: sorry @James_D I am going to upload thanks to tell me

Comment: You're getting a `downvotes` because you've not posted any code, stacktrace(s), and steps you've taken to fix your issue.

Comment: sorry I uploaded now :( @SusannahPotts

Comment: Thank you @Badrkhan.  I'd recommend reading [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) just so you don't have to worry about this in the future.

Comment: You set the `prefWidth` of everything... So of course it won't resize. I have no idea what `JFXHamburger` is, so I don't know how that behaves in terms of layout, but if you hardcode the sizes of things, nothing can change its size. Just choose an appropriate [layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) that behaves the way you want it to behave.

Comment: I am going to build a desktop application that is my group project in college.

Comment: JFXHamburger is just like in android phone we saw that is like that.

Comment: Amazing! your link work ... @James_D one question more the actual software and desktop application also use BorderPan ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, after 1 and half year I learn how to make flexible and dynamic UI design in Javafx.

1. Use BorderPane as a root pane.
2. Put your HBox in BorderPane top. (Use computer size width and height)

This is just one way you could find multiple ways of dynamic UI example on stack or google.

Comment: There was like actually nothing online to specify the very same thing and i was looking for a few days now. Thank you for returning to this